# TextView does not stick to the right

Tags: android

I want to set the `TextView` stick to right top.

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Test.test.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:text="@string/Title1"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I try to set the `TextView`:

- `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`
- `android:layout_marginRight="0dp"`
- `android:layout_marginTop="0dp"`

But nothing work, the `TextView` stay in the left top.

Someone have idea for solution?

**UPDATE:**

How to stick left `TextView`to another `TextView` that stick to the right parent?

I try set the wight and nothing..

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:text="@string/Title1"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:text="@string/Title2" 
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

I want textView2 will be stick to left textView1.

**Find solution to update**
I just set in textview2

- app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView1"
- app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"

Thanks,

Tal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Constraint Layout, set the right constraint of the `TextView` to right of the parent layout to align it to right

Add following constraint to your `TextView`

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

like this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHowMuchSigned"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/Title"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
```